# Widows 10 Active directory user profile desktop not responding after restart and login in outside domain network

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10

Windows Server 2012 R2 active directory profile has been configured in windows 10 pro-64-bit laptop and was working fine early days and recently noticed when we restarted the laptop in outside domain network and after logged in desktop freeze and not responding unable to access task manager or any other software and folders. and the local administrator profile was working fine.

When I connect the laptop to the domain network and tried to log in to the same AD profile and started working and there is no lagging.

what could be the issues? please advise.

Comment: That event does not describe an issue that would result in freezing or lagging. Correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: I was noticed the testing time without domain network and both the testing time and event viewer timing matching this error in the event viewer.

I am not sure whether the New windows 10 version 2004 makes these issues.

Comment: I have tested 2 more PCs, AD user profile works fine in Windows 10 Version 1909 and not working in Windows 10 Version 2004.

Can you advise please do I need to update any patches?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the issues with the below policy.**

It is a policy that is set on the domain controller, called GPO(Group Policy Object). Anyone with enough authorization has the ability to set the number of cached credentials(0-50), by changing GPO. If that number is set to 0, then it will only allow logins when connected to DC. You cant login to your domain account in that case.

If you want to confirm if this is indeed the case, you can check the number of cached logons in Local Security Policy: Start>> type local security policy and enter>> Security Settings>> Local Policies>>Security Options>>Interactive Logon: Number of previous logons to cache

If that number is set to 0 then it is indeed the case. Even if you change that number the GPO will override it. The bottom line is the Organisational Units's(OU's) GPO has the final say in local policies, by default (which can be changed by authorized users ). In this case, you will have to contact your system administrator.